# Create a new dataframe by spliting info in each cell

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
idx obj1  obj2   obj3
1   2Home NA     3Space
2   NA    NA     NA
3   NA    3Space 2Home
```

I want to create two new dataframes: 1) where the columns are just the integer numbers in the front and the other with just the words. The column names would stay the same.

Edit:
This info comes from a csv which I get like so

```
df = read.csv("./Documents/BC-Docs/rating-per-user.csv", na.strings=c("","NA"))
```

Comment: This looks like "answer my homework" type of question. Typically, one is supposed to ask for concrete answer for a specific question, as SO is intended as Q&A website.

Comment: This isn't my homework. Not in school. I am new at R though, @Michael how would you word this question?

Comment: That is why I wrote *looks like* :)

Comment: How I would word it? In such a case, I would write what I did, what I tried, what happens when I try, and what I think is going on. In general, it is a good idea to provide as much info as possible about the context of the problem and what kind of attempts to solve it were made

Comment: Oh! Will do that next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `parse_number` on the character columns by looping `across` to create the first dataset

```
library(dplyr)
out1 <- df1 %>% 
     mutate(across(where(is.character), ~ readr::parse_number(.)))
out1
  idx obj1 obj2 obj3
1   1    2   NA    3
2   2   NA   NA   NA
3   3   NA    3    2
```

Similarly, with `str_remove` to remove all the digits from each column to create second data

```
library(stringr)
out2 <- df1 %>% 
    mutate(across(where(is.character), ~ str_remove(., "\\d+")))
out2
  idx obj1  obj2  obj3
1   1 Home  <NA> Space
2   2 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
3   3 <NA> Space  Home
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(idx = 1:3, obj1 = c("2Home", NA, NA), obj2 = c(NA, 
NA, "3Space"), obj3 = c("3Space", NA, "2Home")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. The first expression gives an error where readr is not a package. While the second expression is not changing my data. (It works for the given dataframe)

Comment: @Kuro You need to install the package with `install.packages('readr')`

Comment: @Kuro Please check the `str(yourdata)`.  i assume the columns as `character` class

Answer (score 0):

We can create a list with the two dataframes with `purrr:map` and `stringr::str_remove` and `dplyr::mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

map(c(character='^\\d', numeric='[^\\d].*'),
    function(x) df1%>%mutate(across(contains('obj'), ~str_remove(.x, x))))

$character
  idx obj1  obj2  obj3
1   1 Home  <NA> Space
2   2 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
3   3 <NA> Space  Home

$numeric
  idx obj1 obj2 obj3
1   1    2 <NA>    3
2   2 <NA> <NA> <NA>
3   3 <NA>    3    2
```

Comment: I get this, Error: unexpected input in:
"map(c(character='^\\d', numeric='[^\\d].*'),
    \"

Comment: R versions earlier than 4.1 do not support the `\(x)` symbol for lambda functions. Use `function(x)` instead, or update your R version. Edited the question

Comment: @Kuro, please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option using `lapply` -

```
cols <- grep('obj', names(df))
#Create copies of original dataframe
df1 <- df
df2 <- df
#Keep only numbers
df1[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], function(x) as.numeric(gsub('\\D', '', x)))
df1

#  idx obj1 obj2 obj3
#1   1    2   NA    3
#2   2   NA   NA   NA
#3   3   NA    3    2

#Keep only characters
df2[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], function(x) gsub('\\d', '', x))
df2

#  idx obj1  obj2  obj3
#1   1 Home  <NA> Space
#2   2 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
#3   3 <NA> Space  Home
```